# express-validator : How to validate "start date" is before "end date"

Tags: validation, express, express-validator, validator.js

I am using `express-validator` to do my server validation and I have come across a little trouble with my date validation. I am trying to validate that my Start Date is before my End Date. I am currently using this:

```
check('taskStartDate', { isBefore : ('taskEndDate' === undefined ) })
.isBefore('taskEndDate').withMessage('Start Date must be before End Date')
```

However, the problem with that is no matter what date I input into my form, whether the start date is before or after the end date, I get my implemented message 'Start Date must be before End Date'. I don't know how else to go about doing this besides a custom validator, which if that is the recommended way, I would appreciate any guidance on how to go about writing the custom validation. I also tried to include sanitization like so:

```
check('taskStartDate').isBefore(sanitizeBody('taskEndDate').toDate())
.withMessage( 'Start Date must be before End Date.')
```

but that did not work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As @gustavohenke wrote, you should create custom validator. Code below is for [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html) version [13.7.0](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js/releases/tag/13.7.0). Main difference to @gustavohenke example is changed validation function to `check()` and in current version this function must return `true` at the end.

```
[
    check('end').toDate(),
    check('start').toDate().custom((startDate, { req }) => {
        if (startDate.getTime() > req.body.end.getTime()) {
            throw new Error('start date must be before end date');
        }
        return true
    })
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a custom validator is the way to go when you want to check a value against another in the request.

You would be interested in the following combo of sanitizers and validator (sanitizers run before the validators, so you can get the value as `Date` objects when using them):

```
[
  sanitize('taskEndDate').toDate(),
  check('taskStartDate').toDate().custom((startDate, { req }) => {
    if (startDate.getTime() >= req.body.taskEndDate.getTime()) {
      throw new Error('start date must be before end date');
    }
    return true;
  })
]
```

[Look at the docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html#example-checking-if-password-confirmation-matches-password) for further examples.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your answer did not work for me unfortunately. Including sanitize is what kept the dates from being correctly validated. I have no clue why. Instead, I just used  `check('taskStartDate').custom((StartDate, { req }) => EndDate >= req.body.taskEndDate ).withMessage(...)` .

Comment: You have to `return true` after if condition

Answer (score 1):

here's a custom validator for checking if the entered date of birth(dob) is valid or not , ie, before today's date.

```
check('dob').custom(value=>{
    let enteredDate=new Date(value);
    let todaysDate=new Date();
    if(enteredDate>todaysDate){
        throw new Error("Invalid Date");
    }
    return true;
})
```

*dob= name of input field for date of birth*

Answer (score 1):

express-validator uses underlying validator.js, so all validator.js middlewares are available in express-validator as well.

check
[validator.js]: https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#validators
for complete list

there is .isAfter() and isBefore().

you can implement this way

```js
check('dateOfMissing', 'Date cannot be in future').Before('dateOfMissing', ['timeinpast']),
check('dateOfMissing', 'Date cannot be in future').isAfter('dateOfMissing', ['time in future']);
```

default is now (current date)